# Join two tables with mismatching number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

Old_table (OT)

```
 Record_id |  Name  |  Sequence_num
------------------------------------
    78     | Austin |  0
    78     | Mike   |  1
    78     | Joe    |  2
```

and

New_table (NT)

```
 Record_id |  Name  |  Sequence_num
------------------------------------
    78     | Mike   |  0
    78     | Joe    |  1
    78     | Austin |  2
    78     | Fred   |  3
    78     | Ben    |  4
```

What I'm looking for is the output table to look like this:

```
 Record_id |  OT_Name  |  NT_Name  |  Sequence_num
---------------------------------------------------
    78     |  Austin   |  Mike     |  0
    78     |  Mike     |  Joe      |  1
    78     |  Joe      |  Austin   |  2
    78     |  NULL     |  Fred     |  3
    78     |  NULL     |  Ben      |  4
```

The issue is that I don't know for certain how many rows will be in each table. OT could have 10 rows and NT could have 3, or NT could have more than OT, or they could have the same number. Any rows that don't have a matching Sequence_num in the opposite table will need to have a NULL value in the appropriate column. Short of creating a function for every table with this situation, how could a select statement accomplish this? I can not for the life of me come up with a solution.

Edit:

Using MS Sql Sever 2008

Management Studio 10.0.1600.22

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a database that supports `FULL OUTER JOIN` syntax then you can use:

```
select 
  coalesce(ot.record_id, nt.record_id) record_id,
  ot.name OT_Name,
  nt.name NT_name,
  coalesce(ot.sequence_num, nt.sequence_num) Sequence_num
from old_table ot
full outer join new_table nt
  on ot.record_id = nt.record_id
  and ot.sequence_num =  nt.sequence_num
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/485a0/5)

Comment: This is close, but I can't change the order of the names in the New_Table

Comment: @Proxy404 see my edit, I changed the join to use the `record_id` and the `sequence_num` and it appears to be correct now.

Comment: This works in the SQL Fiddle perfectly. But it only seems to show the rows that have matching Sequence_nums in my environment. (i.e. it is only showing rows with a sequence_num of 0, 1, and 2)

Comment: @Proxy404 if the `sequence_num` might be missing between the tables, then you can try using a generic `row_number()` for each table and join on that -- see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19a81/3

Comment: @Proxy404: throw in a "where ot.name is null or nt.name is null" if you want to eliminate matching records

Answer (score 2):

The following will work in any database.  It doesn't rely on `full outer join`:

```
select record_id,
       MAX(case when which = 'ot' then name end) as ot_name,
       MAX(case when which = 'nt' then name end) as nt_name,
       sequence_num
from ((select record_id, name, sequence_num, 'ot' as which
       from ot
      ) union all
      (select record_id, name, sequence_num, 'nt' as which
       from nt
      )
     ) t
group by record_id, sequence_num
```